# Confused about argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am having some trouble understanding how argparse works and I've combed through the documentation but am still having some difficulty understanding.

```
def arguments():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test..')
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input-file", required=True, help="input file name")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output-file", required=True, help="output file name")
parser.add_argument("-r", "--row-limit", required=True, help="row limit to split", type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

is_valid_file(parser, args.input_file)

is_valid_csv(parser, args.input_file, args.row_limit)

return args.input_file, args.output_file, args.row_limit

def is_valid_file(parser, file_name):
"""Ensure that the input_file exists"""
if not os.path.exists(file_name):
    parser.error("The file {} does not exist".format(file_name))
    sys.exit(1)

def is_valid_csv(parser, file_name, row_limit):
"""
Ensure that the # of rows in the input_file
is greater than the row_limit.
"""
row_count = 0
for row in csv.reader(open(file_name)):
    row_count += 1
if row_limit > row_count:
    parser.error("More rows than actual rows in the file")
    sys.exit(1)
```

The code above works fine, but once I remove "--row-limit" on line 5, I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File ".\csv_split.py", line 95, in <module>
  arguments = arguments()
 File ".\csv_split.py", line 33, in arguments
  is_valid_csv(parser, args.input_file, args.row_limit)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'row_limit'
```

Why does removing the "--row-limit" present me with this error?

Comment: You are wondering why when you remove the parameter it is no longer there?

Comment: In `is_valid_csv(parser, args.input_file, args.row_limit)` you're using `args.row_limit`. If you don't parse it, it won't exist in `args`, and accessing it produces an error.

Comment: Print `args` after parsing so you have a clear idea of the the parser has done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args = parser.parse_args()` actually adds an attribute to the namespace `args` for each `parser.add_argument` call. The name of the attribute is generated from your argument name, here `--row-limit` is transformed to `row_limit` because you can't have dashes in variable names. See the [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments) for details.

So when you call `parser.add_argument(..., "--row-limit", ...)`, it creates `args.row_limit` once you invoke `parse_args()`. As [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) mentioned, you use `args.row_limit` later on in your code. But if you remove the `--row-limit` argument from the parser, the attribute  `row_limit` won't exist in `args`.

Comment: Makes total sense now, thank you Carsten and Amadan!